# Messages are lost when master node in rabbitmq restarts

Tags: rabbitmq

I have deployed RabbitMQ 3 node cluster(3 pods) on the AKS cluster and also enabled mirroring. Whenever the RabbitMQ master node pod restarts, the messages published by the application to the RabbitMQ are lost, till the new master node is set in the RabbitMQ cluster. Is there a way to avoid the loss of the messages when the master node of RabbitMQ deployed as a pod is restarted??

Comment: How have you confirmed mirroring is enabled?

Comment: I checked from the RabbitMQ management UI

Comment: Was the replication configured before of after the messages were queued?